# loop sheet cells.find only work if sheet is manually selected

Tags: excel, vba

Friends, Good day! For the last week I have been trying every imaginable way of trying to solve the issue I am having. Here is my code:

Sub LoopTest()

```
Dim Current As Worksheet
Dim range3 As Range


Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Activate

    For Each Current In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set range3 = Cells.Find(What:="AAIDL00", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not range3 Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print range3.Value

    Exit For
        Else: Debug.Print "Search term not found!"

        End If
    Next
```

End Sub

I am looking for "AAIDL00" in a test workbook with 8 sheets. This string is located on sheet8 cell R22. The script work when I manually select (click on) sheet8 on the workbook. But, when I have any other sheet selected, the script returns "Search term not found!".

Can somebody please help me with this? I have been all over the forums and seem the code is more or less "standard" in structure. I don't understand why I am getting this error. Something tells me this is a global setting issue with my PC or maybe even the excel installation. Not sure. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Use `current.Cells.Find( ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use one or more With ... End With blocks to provide definitive parent worksheet and workbook references.

```
Sub LoopTest()
    Dim w As Long, range3 As Range

    With Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")
        For w = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
            With .Worksheets(w)
                Set range3 = .Cells.Find(What:="AAIDL00", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                If Not range3 Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print range3.Value
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Search term not found in " & .Name
                End If
            End With
        Next w
    End With
End Sub
```

Note the `.` prefix on worksheets, cells and range. This provides parentage from the immediately preceding With ... End With block.